# Qt - Reimplementation of QIODevice to hear my own voice in realtime

Tags: c++, qt, audio, buffer

I'm subclassing the `QIODevice` class to write and read voice via a `QAudioInput`and a `QAudioOutput` instance. But when I read it in my headphone, the sound has little cuts each few milliseconds. It gives a really bad sound and if I keep the microphone open, when I close it, the sound continue for a long time.

In other words :

- I say "AAAAAA" in the microphone
- I hear "AA - AA - AA" in my headphone

I already try to use an other `QIODevice` implementation such as `QFile` and it works well, the sound was good. It means that the problem isn't in my `QAudioInput` and `QAudioOutput` instance.

The only thing that I do when I want to hear my voice is :

```cpp
void startrecording()
{
    _audioInput->start(_audioBuffer);
    _audioOutput->start(_audioBuffer);
    // Start the output after didn't really change the sound
    // QTimer::singleShot(500, [this] { _audioOutput->start(_audioBuffer); });
}
```

Now here is my `AudioBuffer` class

```cpp
// .h
class AudioBuffer : public QIODevice
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    AudioBuffer();

  protected:
    qint64 writeData(const char* data, qint64 len) override;
    qint64 readData(char* data, qint64 maxlen) override;

  private:
    static const int MAXSIZE = 1024 * 1024;

    std::array<char, MAXSIZE> _buffer;
    qint64                    _writePosition;
    qint64                    _readPosition;
    qint64                    _currentBufferLength;
};
```

```cpp
// .cpp
AudioBuffer::AudioBuffer()
{
    _writePosition       = 0;
    _readPosition        = 0;
    _currentBufferLength = 0;
}

qint64 AudioBuffer::writeData(const char* data, qint64 len)
{
    qDebug() << "--- writing ---" << data;

    std::string content = data;

    if ((_writePosition + content.size()) > MAXSIZE)
    {
        qint64 firstData = MAXSIZE - _writePosition;
        memcpy(&_buffer[_writePosition], content.data(), firstData);
        memcpy(&_buffer[0], content.data() + firstData, content.size() - firstData);
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(&_buffer[_writePosition], content.data(), content.size());
    }

    _writePosition = (_writePosition + content.size()) % MAXSIZE;
    _currentBufferLength += content.size();

    return len;
}

qint64 AudioBuffer::readData(char* data, qint64 maxlen)
{
    if (_currentBufferLength <= 0) return 0;

    qint64 writeLen = std::min(maxlen, _currentBufferLength);
    if ((writeLen + _readPosition) > MAXSIZE)
    {
        qint64 firstData = MAXSIZE - _readPosition;
        memcpy(data, &_buffer[_readPosition], firstData);
        memcpy(data + firstData, &_buffer[0], writeLen - firstData);
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(data, &_buffer[_readPosition], writeLen);
    }

    qDebug() << "--- reading ---" << data;

    _readPosition = (_readPosition + writeLen) % MAXSIZE;
    _currentBufferLength -= writeLen;

    return writeLen;
}
```

Both `qDebug` data return the same output, just `readData` is less called than `writeData` but the buffer is correctly read.

The output (without the data) is the following (for 5 seconds). i don't know if it's means something but more time passed, more `writeData` is called compare to `readData`

```
--- writing --- x1
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x1
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x2
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x1
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x1
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x1
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x1
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x3
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x1
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x6
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x9
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x13
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x1
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x20
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x1
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x26
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x26
--- reading --- x1
--- writing --- x4
input stop
--- reading --- x2
```

Comment: Just an idea. I suppose you read and write synchronously, i.e. in the same thread (main). This may cause interruptions of reading/writing - thus you hear a segmented sound.

Comment: You are aware that you are printing raw audio as if it is text? The output is meaningless. I would recommend that you write down for yourself exactly how you think audio is represented, what the arguments to writeData are, the arguments to readData, and what you then print.

Comment: @vahancho It is indeed on one thread. I never worked with thread yet, so I will try your solution and come back for feelings afterwards.

Comment: @vahancho Okay, so before doing this on different thread, I wrote first, then read, and I have much less lags but still have some. Any idea ?

Comment: @MSalters Okay, I tried with a `QBuffer` and it works well, but for my implementation, I need more than what a `QBuffer` do. But I don't see the difference between [QBuffer cpp file](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/src/corelib/io/qbuffer.cpp#L422) and my implementation, they are very close

Answer (score 0):

So after some trials, It seems that using a `QBuffer` can replace my `AudioBuffer` in this case.

Then, be careful because if you read and write at the same time in the same thread, it will cause some lags.

But in my case, I needed to send data to a server, then the server send the audio to every clients able to hear it. So the `QBuffer` wasn't enough.

So here is my new implementation

```cpp
// Moving in different thread
_audioInput->moveToThread(&_inputThread);
_audioOutput->moveToThread(&_outputThread);

_audioInput->start(_audioBuffer);
_audioOutput->start(_audioBuffer);
```

```cpp
// .cpp
class AudioBuffer : public QBuffer
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    AudioBuffer(/* Whatever you need for your server connection */);

  protected:
    /// Override the QBuffer method
    qint64 writeData(const char* data, qint64 len) override;

    /// Connect this method with the signal emit when your server send new audio
    /// This is a string but it can be whatever you want according to your server
    void getServerAudio(const std::string& audio);
};
```

```cpp
// .h
AudioBuffer::AudioBuffer(/* Whatever you need for your server connection */)
{
    // Connect your server with AudioBuffer::getServerAudio
}

qint64 AudioBuffer::writeData(const char* data, qint64 len)
{
    // Send that the client send a new audio to the server
    std::string audio = data;
    // This is an example
    sendAudioToServer(audio);

    return len;
}

void AudioBuffer::getServerAudio(const std::string& audio)
{
    // When you get a new audio from the server, you can hear it (so you write data into the buffer)
    QBuffer::writeData(audio.c_str(), audio.size());
}
```